# Is there a preposition for "composed of"?

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

I'm writing a story where there's a federation of minor planets that uses Esperanto as its official language. I'm trying to call them something like "the federation of minor planets", because I'm not creative, and came up with "Federacio de la Planedetoj". However, I'm looking for something that means "composed of", and "de" doesn't seem to mean that. I guess I could make something up about how they specifically chose "de" to emphasize that they're controlled by the minor planets, but I'd still prefer to find a preposition that means the right thing.

**TL;DR**: What's the word for "composed of"?

Incidentally, if anyone wants to provide a better translation for any other part of the phrase, please do.

Comment: The _World Organisation of Young Esperantists_ is called _Tutmonda Esperantista Junulara Organizo_. In analogy to that you could call it _Malgranda Planeda Federacio_, or _Planedeta Federacio_

Comment: @Oliver You should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As much as English "federation of minor planets" conveys what you intend, also Esperanto "Federacio de (malgrandaj) planedoj" is the adequate expression.

There is no more specific preposition for "composed of". When you speak about something concrete made of certain elements, the preposition *el* would be the right choice (*kuko el faruno, butero kaj ovoj* 'a cake made of flour, butter, and eggs'), but it doesn't fit something abstract like a federation.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine, you may like the word *Planedetaro* as a single word (possibly written with uppercase P to refer to *the* special federation of small planets). This word does not convey the "federation" meaning, but maybe this is not absolutely necessary.

`ar` is the suffix to describe a group of similar items, e.g. *arbo* - tree, *arbaro* - forest.

Answer (score 2):

The *World Organisation of Young Esperantists* is called *Tutmonda Esperantista Junulara Organizo*. In analogy to that you could call it *Malgranda Planeda Federacio*, or *Planedeta Federacio*.

Comment: TEJO is an _organizo_ and this _organizo_ is _tutmonda_, _Esperantista_ and _junulara_, but the _Federacio_ we are talking about is not (I suppose) _malgranda_. That's why _Malganda Planeda Federacio_ is not a good translation of "Federation of Minor Planets".  _Planedeta Federacio_ is OK. _Malgrandplaneda Federacio_ is possible.

Comment: Why not include the -ar- suffix? So, *Federacio Planedetara*.